# Pygame (A bit racey) game bug

Tags: python, pygame

in the game when you first start it there's the game start menu/intro, it has 2 buttons (Start Game) (Quit)

Now when you start the game and you're actually playing, when you press P (Paused) there're 2 buttons (Continue) (Main Menu) if you click continue it completes the game normally. However when you click main menu it closes the game instead of returning to the intro, same problem is present when you crash with the car you have (Try Again) and (Main Menu) and also if you click Main Menu it closes the game

Any ideas on what might be the problem ?(ignore the comments)

```
import pygame
import time
import random

pygame.init()

crash_sound = pygame.mixer.Sound("C:\Users\itzrb_000\Documents\Untitled.wav")
pygame.mixer.music.load("C:\Users\itzrb_000\Downloads\Cool_Ride.mp3")

display_width = 800
display_height = 600

black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
red = (200,0,0)
green = (0,200,0)
blue = (0,0,255)

bright_green = (0,255,0)
bright_red = (255,0,0)

car_width = 50

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))#game screen size
pygame.display.set_caption('What A Ride')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

carImg = pygame.image.load('C:\Users\itzrb_000\Downloads\Car_Green_Front.png')
gameBackground = pygame.image.load('C:\WhatARide_Background.png')
icon = pygame.image.load('C:\Users\itzrb_000\Downloads\Car_Green_Front - Copy.png')

pygame.display.set_icon(icon)

pause = False

car1 = pygame.image.load('C:\Users\itzrb_000\Downloads\download (3).png')
car2 = pygame.image.load('C:\Users\itzrb_000\Downloads\download (2).png')
car3 = pygame.image.load('C:\Users\itzrb_000\Downloads\images.png')
rock = pygame.image.load('C:\Users\itzrb_000\Downloads\Rock.png')

def background():
    gameDisplay.blit(gameBackground,(0,0))

'''def cars(ystart):
    objects = [car1, car2, car3, rock]
    num_of_objects = random.randint(1,4)
    for x in range(num_of_objects):
        y = random.choice(objects)
        objectblit = random.randrange(130, 625) - (y.get_width())
        gameDisplay.blit(y,(random.randrange(130, 625)))'''

def score(count):
    font = pygame.font.SysFont(None,25)
    text = font.render("Score: "+str(count),True, blue)
    gameDisplay.blit(text,(0,0))

def things(thingx, thingy, thingw, thingh, color):
    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, color, [thingx, thingy, thingw, thingh])

def car(x,y):
    gameDisplay.blit(carImg,(x,y))

def text_objects(text,font):
    textSurface = font.render(text, True, white)
    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()

def message_display(text):
    largeText = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf',115)
    TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects(text, largeText)
    TextRect.center = ((display_width*0.5),(display_height*0.5))
    gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)#blit display object

    pygame.display.update()

    time.sleep(2)

    game_loop()

def crash():
    pygame.mixer.music.stop()
    pygame.mixer.Sound.play(crash_sound)

    largeText = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf", 115)
    TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("You Crashed", largeText)
    TextRect.center = ((display_width * 0.5), (display_height * 0.5))
    gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)  # blit display object
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
        button("Try Again!", 300, 400, 200, 50, green, bright_green, game_loop)
        button("Main Menu!", 300, 470, 200, 50, red, bright_red, game_intro)

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(20)

def button(msg,x,y,w,h,ic,ac,action=None):
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    if x+w > mouse[0] > x and y+h > mouse[1] > y:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, ac,(x,y,w,h))

        if click[0] == 1 and action != None:
            action()
    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, ic,(x,y,w,h))

    smallText = pygame.font.SysFont("freesansbold.ttf",20)
    textSurf, textRect = text_objects(msg, smallText)
    textRect.center = ( (x+(w/2)), (y+(h/2)) )
    gameDisplay.blit(textSurf, textRect)

def quitgame():
    pygame.quit()
    quit()

def unpause():
    global pause
    pause = False
    pygame.mixer.music.unpause()
def paused():
    global pause
    pause = True
    pygame.mixer.music.pause()
    largeText = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf", 115)
    TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("Paused", largeText)
    TextRect.center = ((display_width * 0.5), (display_height * 0.5))
    gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)  # blit display object
    while pause == True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
        button("Continue!", 300, 400, 200, 50, green, bright_green,unpause)
        button("Main Menu", 300, 470, 200, 50, red, bright_red,game_intro)

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(20)

def game_intro():
    intro = True

    while intro:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        gameDisplay.fill(blue)
        largeText = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms", 115)
        TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("What A Ride", largeText)
        TextRect.center = ((display_width / 2), (display_height / 2))
        gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

        button("Start Game", 300, 400, 200, 50, green, bright_green,game_loop)
        button("Quit", 300, 470, 200, 50, red, bright_red,quitgame)

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(20)


def game_loop():
    global pause
    pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)
    x = (display_width * 0.45)
    y = (display_height * 0.8)

    x_change = 0

    thing_startx = random.randrange(130,625)
    thing_starty = -600
    thing_speed = 5
    thing_width = 100
    thing_height = 100

    dodged = 0

    gameExit = False

    while not gameExit:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    x_change = -5
                elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    x_change = 5
                if event.key == pygame.K_p:
                    pause = True
                    paused()

            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    x_change = 0

            print event
        x += x_change

        background()
        things(thing_startx, thing_starty, thing_width, thing_height, black)
        thing_starty += thing_speed
        car(x,y)
        score(dodged)

        if x > 625 - car_width or x < 130:
            crash()

        if thing_starty > display_height:
            thing_starty = 0 - thing_height
            thing_startx = random.randrange(130,625)
            dodged += 1
            thing_speed += 1
            thing_width += (dodged*1.2)
        if y < thing_starty+thing_height:
            if x > thing_startx and x < thing_startx + thing_width or x + car_width > thing_startx and x + car_width < thing_startx+thing_width:
                crash()
        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(51) #fps
game_intro()
game_loop()
pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're not waiting for the mouse button to be released before you trigger your buttons.

- When `pause()` starts, it brings up two buttons.
- User moves mouse to `Main Menu`.
- User clicks mouse.
- As soon as the mouse button is depressed, `game_intro()` is called, which puts a `Quit` button in the same place.
- The mouse button is *still* depressed, so the game quits.