# Pygame (A bit racey) Objects are there, but not visible

Tags: python, pygame

I have a couple of objects defined/entered into a variable

```
car1 = pygame.image.load('C:\Users\itzrb_000\Downloads\download (3).png')
car2 = pygame.image.load('C:\Users\itzrb_000\Downloads\download (2).png')
car3 = pygame.image.load('C:\Users\itzrb_000\Downloads\images.png')
rock = pygame.image.load('C:\Users\itzrb_000\Downloads\Rock.png')
```

Then created a function called `cars` which takes the x and y start position as arguments

```
def cars(thingx, thingy):
    objects = [car1, car2, car3, rock]
    num_of_objects = random.randint(1,4)
    for x in range(num_of_objects):
        y = random.choice(objects)
        gameDisplay.blit(y,(random.randrange(130, 625),-300))
```

inside the `game_loop` function

```
thing_startx = random.randrange(130,625)
thing_starty = -600
thing_speed = 10
```

Then I call all the objects

```
background()
things(thing_startx, thing_starty, thing_width, thing_height, black)
car(x,y)
cars(thing_startx, thing_starty)
thing_starty += thing_speed
score(dodged)
```

`car` is the car that the player plays with, `things` is a function that draws a black square that later on is the thing that I shouldn't crash into

```
def things(thingx, thingy, thingw, thingh, color):
    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, color, [thingx, thingy, thingw, thingh])
```

I'm trying to display the car images instead of just a black block, I commented out the `things` function and its call in `game_loop`. When I tested there's nothing visible, however I noticed that my car at some point crashes, so the conclusion is that the car image is there, but it's not visible.

Any idea on how to solve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're blitting the objects off screen. `gameDisplay.blit(y,(random.randrange(130, 625),-300))` will blit the image at x between 130 to 625 and y at -300 (which means 300 to the left of the screen).

But is the function doing what you want it to do? Every loop you're blitting a random number of random objects at random positions. I strongly suggest finding a better tutorial which teaches basics as code structure, good naming, how to use docstrings and object-oriented programming, like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bMt47wvK6u0&list=PL4Yp6gRH-R1Birdm-Gs-SdBFWLUC1q3Fa&index=4).

Comment: Full code, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39502475/pygame-a-bit-racey-game-bug

but you'll notice some changes from this one and the one in the link

Comment: I believe I found the problem. I've updated the answer

Comment: it worked, thanks alot, there's a new problem but i'm figuring it out on my own. Again thanks